# Where's the list of available functions or API available to me by default in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I must be bad at searching, but I can't find documentation on what available functions or APIs there are for use in a Jenkinsfile (Groovy syntax).

For example, where is `build job:` documented? Is that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All available steps (includes build-in and plugin supplied) can be found [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/)

The document of `build job` at [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#-build-%20build%20a%20job)

Comment: Ah, I see. I saw that page before, but wasn't sure that was it. I was looking for something that looked more like API reference for a function, rather than something that looked like a schema.

Comment: The docs are messy. Now I know, I need to search for `build: ` in order to find what I'm looking for. So, I finally just found `sh: ` in order to see about the `sh` command. Now I know! Thanks.